# PopUpWindow is getting truncated when used with ListView Item

Tags: android, listview, popupwindow

I have a `ListView` in which I have to update the item depending on the user status.
User can update the status by clicking on it and `PopupWindow` is displayed. But when user clicks on last item on `ListView` then `PopupWindow` is getting truncated.

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question.
I have figured out how android `PopupWindow` works.
If we don't give width or height for the popupwindow i.e; wrap_content or match_parent the placing is not calculated.
If we give the width or height of popupwindow then PopupWindow checks if it can fit with the given anchor and if Yes it draws below the anchor otherwise it is adjusted.

What I have done is given a width to popupwindow and created.

Problem Solved

Thanks to me ;)